# What's the most accurate method to identify which lead is an opportunity/contact/account converted from

Tags: apex, trigger, lead-conversion

Just started to work with the lead conversion.

What's the most accurate method to identify which lead is an opportunity/contact/account converted from?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a calculation on the Lead that is equal to `LeadId` for each field that you want to map - ie `Opportunity_Lead_Id__c` and `Account_Lead_Id__c`.

Then create similar fields on Opportunity and Account - Just call them `From_Lead__c` or `Lead_id__c`.

Then map them in the lead mapping area.

Note - you need a separate calc field on Lead for each field that you want to map, that's why you'll need three similar fields on the lead to map to Account, Contact and Opportunity.

Comment: Thanks, this is the method I am thinking but 3 same fields on lead made me hesitated to proceed.

Comment: Right now, I can't think of another way, but I'm having a wee look to see if there are any other techniques out there.

Comment: Take a look at my other answer - I reckon it's better in some cases, if you feel like writing some code

Comment: Use the fields that salesforce.com gave you!

Comment: Are these fields present already? :/

Comment: CaspNZ, I am writing a trigger to process the created account/opportunity and contact. This trigger is only for one type of my lead so I don't want to create a VF page for every types of my lead.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to do anything special, as this data is automatically linked for you. Leads, once converted, have three fields populated: ConvertedContactId, ConvertedAccountId, and ConvertedOpportunityId. You can run reports and SOQL queries on those leads to see which lead the account/contact/opportunity came from. You get this for free. There's even a Lead with Converted Lead information report you can run out of the box.

Comment: So I am able to fetch these data from the after update trigger of lead after the lead is converted.  Thank you for much

Comment: Actually, this data is stored on the Lead, not the Opp, Contact and Account. It's handy to have it on those records, so I think my answer stills stands.

Comment: I'd probably add three fields and a mapping over adding stuff to a trigger that you need to write unit tests for.

Comment: @CaspNZ Sure, it depends on the use case, but ordinarily, you don't care about the lead much afterwards so much as "during" the conversion, in which case, you'd ordinarily want to just do so in the Lead's AfterUpdate trigger event.

Comment: Good point. I was going to remove the answer, but I feel it has some value now... On the other hand, the fact that these fields exist is great to hear and has a lot of value too. Probably more. :)

Comment: Excellent piece of information..actually i am implementing round robin of assigning leads to queue members...so when lead is converted i cannot be able to take decision  on that...so this will be more useful to me.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here's another way. 
You can override the convert lead button and redirect to your own VisualForce page.

Essentially, in the page controller, you will call something like this:

```
Database.LeadConvert lc = new database.LeadConvert();
lc.setLeadId(lObj.Id);        
lc.setConvertedStatus(convertStatus.MasterLabel);               
Database.LeadConvertResult lcr = Database.convertLead(lc);

Id oppId = lcr.getOpportunityId();

Once you have that, you can query for the opportunity and set whatever fields you like. The same applies for Accounts and Contacts
```

These methods are available on the LeadConvertResult:

```
getAccountId() 
getContactId() 
getErrors() 
getLeadId()
getOpportunityId() 
isSuccess()
```